# Convert bytes to MB in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a size in bytes. I want to convert this everytime in MB. But my code is giving the wrong answer.

```
sub sizeConversion {
    my $size = shift;
    return ($size / (1024 * 1024));
}

my $size = 1024;
my $size_conversion = &sizeConversion($size);
print $size_conversion;
```

I get the output as:

```
0.0009765625
```

But I am supposed to get the output as

```
0.001024MB
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You better take a calculator to verify your assumption what 1/1024 really is (hint: it is not 0.001024)

Comment: 1024 bytes -> 1KB -> 1/1024 MB. But the result of 1/1024 is not 0.001024 because the power 2 of 1024 isn't 1000000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that there are two kinds of Mega Bytes(MB) in the IT world.

(A) 1 MB = 1 million (1,000,000) bytes.

This MB is used to presents capacity of hard disk drives, DVD and BD,  and communication capacity in the networks, etc.

(B) 1 MB (more precisely 1 MiB) = bytes can be addressed by 20 address lines = 2^20 (1,048,576) bytes.

This MB is used to presents capacity of semiconductor memory like RAM, ROM.

You may know data in RAM is addressed by several address lines each of them has value 0 or 1. If a memory has 10 address lines and 8 data lines, 2^10(1024) addresses of bytes(8 bits) can be stored. The capacity of such memory was not called '1 kilo and 24 bytes memory' but '1 Kilo bytes memory'. By increase of memory capacity, 2^20 bytes memory became to be called 1 Mega bytes memory.

If you use the word "MB" in sense of (A), you should correct the line in your code

```
return ($size / (1024 * 1024));
```

to

```
return ($size / (1000 * 1000));
```

The corrected code will give you the answer 0.001024 MB.

If you use the word "MB" in sense of (B), 0.0009765625 MB is correct answer.

There are two kind of MB, so there are two kind of correct answer.

It depends you which is the answer you want get.

Comment: Actually there is just one kind of `MB`, the second kind that you mentioned is named `MiB` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Answer (score 5):

You get `0.0009765625` because that's the correct answer for what you have defined.

To get `0.001024`, you would have to divide `1024` by `1000000`

Whether a `MB` is `2^20` bytes or `10^6` bytes depends on whether you are programming in assembly or selling hard drives.  See [Wikipedia: Megabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte)

According to Wikipedia the official SI unit is `10^6` or `1000000` bytes.

Comment: Not related to answer; I'm afraid that [Mebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) sounds moronic, like would Babybyte, or Maybebyte.

Comment: Actually the "correct" answer is that 1 `MB` is always 1000 `KB` and this is 1000 bytes. So MB is always 10^6. If you want to calculate with 1024 than the correct ending is `MiB`. Just because a lot of people define MB as 1024 KB doesn't make it right.